# Substitution for an unavailable flash memory chip?

Tags: datasheet, flash, substitution

I need to find a replacement for a particular flash chip that is currently in a device.

The chip in question is the KH25V16066

https://www.macronix.com.hk/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/272/KH25V16066ver12-1.2.pdf

Which is apparently a Hong Kong version of the same US chip, the MX25V16066 (which is also unavailable).

I did however find something close, using Digikey's search UI... the MX25V1635F

Which is the closest thing I could find that shares all the same features and specs of the original.

https://www.macronix.com/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/7409/MX25V1635F%2c%202.5V%2c%2016Mb%2c%20v1.4.pdf

The main difference that I can see is that it also supports x4 read, whereas the original only supports x1/x2

Comparing the datasheets side by side I can see that many of the pages are identical.

I was hoping someone who is more experienced in this area could tell me if this would work as a replacement.

The device in question uses an ARM STM32F030 microcontroller as the main MCU, and it is with that chip that it accesses this flash chip to store and retrieve user data (if that is helpful at all).

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

Upon [closer examination](https://www.macronix.com/Lists/ApplicationNote/Attachments/2089/AN0834V1-Comparison%20of%20Macronix%20MX25V16066_MX25L1606E_MX25V1635F%20and%20MX25V1606F.pdf), it appears they also make a MX25V1606F version of this chip that runs at 104MHz. It is actually a better match otherwise; would there be any issue using a 104MHz chip in place of the 80MHz original?

**UPDATE 2:**

I'm not sure why someone closed this question. I wasn't really asking for a recommendation where to purchase something, but rather *how* to determine what chip would be suitable, by comparing datasheets. The latter is definitely a relevant question that would help other people in the future.

Anyway- I ordered some of the MX25V1606F and they are working great! That chip is actually not supported by my TL866ii Plus programmer, but by using the profile for the MX25L1605A, the programmer is able to read and write to this chip. So after removing the KH25V16066, dumping it, and then writing that dump to the MX25V1606F, and swapping it with the original by hot-air soldering it into the device, it has no idea I have defeated its security!

(I realize this was not necessary, as I could have just experimented with the original, but I really didn't want to risk bricking it if I made a mistake)

Thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: Stand in line - everyone else is having similar issues.

Comment: [Relevant application note](https://www.macronix.com/Lists/ApplicationNote/Attachments/2089/AN0834V1-Comparison%20of%20Macronix%20MX25V16066_MX25L1606E_MX25V1635F%20and%20MX25V1606F.pdf).

Comment: @Chris from looking at that document, it appears every single command on the 16066 is the same on the 1635F, with the exception of RDP (Release from Deep Power Down), which is "0xAB" on the 16066 and "CS# toggle" on the 1635F. Would this be enough to prevent compatibility?

Comment: @benram14159 you can answer that better than anyone here - only you know if your application even puts the IC into "Deep Power Down" which it might need to be released from.

Comment: @brhans unfortunately I can't. I have no access to the source code stored in the MCU, and I don't have the experience necessary to use a logic analyzer to get that info otherwise.

Comment: Even if someone has experience with either chip, there are still too many unknowns. Such is the nature of finding compatible replacements. I must say that you have tried to describe your problem as best as you could. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer released an [application note](https://www.macronix.com/Lists/ApplicationNote/Attachments/2089/AN0834V1-Comparison%20of%20Macronix%20MX25V16066_MX25L1606E_MX25V1635F%20and%20MX25V1606F.pdf) comparing the MX25V16066 and MX25V1635F. There are a few differences that are not just straight upgrades. For instance:

- The two chips have a different method to trigger the RDP command
- The two chips have a different device ID
- The MX25V1635F has a higher standby current than the MX25V16066

Without more information about the circuit and the MCU programming nobody can promise you that these or other small differences wouldn't be problems.

Comment: So originally I had only searched for chips matching all the same parameters as the original, so I missed the MX25V1606F which is mentioned in that doc. The 1606F has like values for those three things you mentioned. The only difference is the clock speed. Would it be OK to substitute a 104MHz chip for an 80MHz chip?

Comment: @benram14159 The clock speed alone *probably* isn't an issue, because that is a maximum clock, so it can operate at a lower clock speed. But without knowing the details of what you're putting it in, nobody can be sure that some subtlety like the higher standby current 
and faster timings definitely won't cause a problem.

Comment: Great, thank you so much for the help. I will just order some of each as they are only a few cents. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: BTW, a similar question- what about using my chip programmer to dump the contents of  this chip... I have a TL866ii Plus which lists only the MX25V1635F on its compatibility list. Would I be able to dump the MX25V16066 using the profile for the 1635F?
I realize the answer is probably the same but I thought Id ask.